# Is there a database agnostic way to perform an ISNUMERIC check in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle10g, oracle19c, database-agnostic

I have a query like below. I may be switching between SQL Server, Oracle etc. Is there a database agnostic way to perform an `ISNUMERIC` check in a query?

```
SELECT name 
FROM Students 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(columnName) = 0
```

I tried using `REGEXP_LIKE` and similar things but they all favour certain DB types and not others.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC`, as I note [elsewhere](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/), is a *terrible* function anyway; don't use it in the first place.

Comment: I can't speak for Oracle but IsNumeric in sql server is a joke. It returns true for way too many non-numeric values (¢, 1e3, ., etc). I don't think there is a consistent query that will work in any DBMS. But then most of the other queries only mostly work in any DBMS. Once you get to anything more complicated than basic selects and aggregation the syntax changes anyway.

Comment: As for the question, there's very few features that are cross-database compatible; you either should be using something to "translate" your application code to database code, or writing specific solutions for different RDBMS.

Comment: First, IsNumeric isn't a joke.  It does exactly what it was designed to do.  I determines if SQL Server COULD convert the value to SOME/ANY numeric datatype in T-SQL.  1E3 IS a valid numeric value!  Please see the following now very old article.  The problem with the IsNumeric function is that people think that means "IsAllDigits", and it patently does NOT mean that. The article also has a simple method for an "IsAllDigits" bit of functionality. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-doesn%e2%80%99t-isnumeric-work-correctly-sql-spackle

Comment: @JeffModen all valid points and far more eloquently getting the point across than I was.

Comment: Although true, @JeffModen , the problem is that `ISNUMERIC` doesn't tell you *what* data type(s) that value will convert to, which is the *real* problem. If you could tell it the destination data type, `ISNUMERIC(<Some Literal String>,int)` that would be much better, as then you can't have a scenario with `CONVERT(int,CASE ISNUMERIC(<Some Literal String>) WHEN 1 THEN <Some Literal String> END)` returning a conversion error, as the value was `'1.23'`.

Comment: Why would you even use that function. Isn't your data properly validated before being added to the database?

Comment: @ThomA - I totally agree that it could be more useful.  Consider this, though... take the string of '20*3'.  Do you consider that to be "numeric" in any way, shape, or form?  Some people might and trying to figure it out using Cast/Convert is going to take substantially longer to determine even if Cast/Convert should be used on it. Like I said, IsNumeric works precisely as advertised. Just because we don't have a use for it, doesn't mean it's a joke. It's useful to someone.  ;-)

Comment: @JeffModen _Like I said, IsNumeric works precisely as advertised. Just because we don't have a use for it, doesn't mean it's a joke._ Maybe it's not a joke, but it definitely has behaviours that aren't advertised in the [ISNUMERIC (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) help which says, _ISNUMERIC returns 1 when the input expression evaluates to a valid numeric data type; otherwise it returns 0._ And yet things like `SELECT ISNUMERIC(CHAR(9))` returns 1 while `SELECT CAST(CHAR(9) AS numeric)` explodes for `float`, `int`, and `numeric`.

Comment: The `money` type exists, @AlwaysLearning . [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OZH6Bpbp).